# BTC in memory pool

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Status: 0/unconfirmed, in memory pool
I transferred btc to a paper wallet earlier today - about eight hours.
The transfer is still "unconfirmed"
I have never seen this before.
There seems to be a massive spike in traffic today.
I "assume" that the btc will be returned to me once the transfer fails.
Any ideas?